# I want to use django with celery (redis). Do I need to install redis on the server of my django application ? or can I have a seperate redis server?

Tags: django, redis, celery

I installed redis on an ubuntu server following [these guidlines](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-20-04). I want to use it with celery for a Django application. My Django application is running on another server. Now I'm confused however on how to set the Django settings, since everywhere I looked I could only find writings about a ["localhost"](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/redis.html#broker-redis). Is it possible to use celery and django with redis on another server ? What Django settings.py do I need to add ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just on your settings do:

`CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://'+REDIS_HOST+':6379/'+REDIS_DB`

Where `REDIS_HOST` is your redis IP and `REDIS_DB` your db (this one is optional)

Comment: @wallucas , understand the REDIS_HOST part. 

But do I need to specify the REDIS_DB as in 

 ` CACHES = {
  "default": {
    "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
    "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0",
    "OPTIONS": {
      "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient"
    }
} `

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://'+REDIS_HOST+':6379/0'

Comment: what do the 0, 1 or 2 stand for ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234345/discussion-between-jefferson-and-walucas).

Comment: I used "CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://'+REDIS_HOST+':6379/"

But when tryin to run the celery - server ('>celery -A FAM worker -l info')

I got this error : 

ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://<IP>:6379/0: Error 10061 connecting to <IP>:6379. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it..

Comment: Can you telnet or ping from django to redis?

Comment: Pinging <IP> with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from <IP>: bytes=32 time=47ms TTL=49
Reply from <IP>: bytes=32 time=42ms TTL=49
Reply from <IP>: bytes=32 time=40ms TTL=49
Reply from <IP>: bytes=32 time=40ms TTL=49

Ping statistics for <IP>:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 40ms, Maximum = 47ms, Average = 42ms